# Can I put Newsstand into a folder?

Tags: ios, newsstand

In iOS5 (and later) my newsstand icon will not go into a folder on either my iPod touch, or my iPad2. Anyone have any suggestions on how to move this application?

Comment: [Nobody puts Baby in a folder.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28A9Jgo92GQ)

Comment: Is there any chance we could get you to accept the iOS 7 correct answer (assuming the accepted answer doesn't get updated now that I'm promoting this question with a bounty)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the latest iOS 7, you can place Newsstand in a folder without having to buy apps or jailbreak your device.

Comment: Can we get a "Finally!" from the chorus?

Comment: @bmike Yes, this: http://venturebeat.com/2013/06/13/iphone-users-rejoice-in-ios-7-newstand-can-finally-be-hidden-but-not-deleted/

Answer (score 16):

Looks like there is a way after all (even if it's most probably a bug because it renders Newsstand useless):

From [The Coding Massacre](http://thecodingmassacre.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/newsstand-folder-no-jailbreak-ios-5/):

1. Take two apps and go to create a folder
2. The second the apps are in the folder and it’s doing the folder creation animation, drag Newsstand into the folder
3. As long as you’re quick enough Newsstand will go into the folder

If you open Newsstand while it’s in a folder your springboard will crash.

Comment: Good find, though this will likely get patched in a couple of weeks.  Probably the way to permanently do this is jailbreak.

Comment: This works, but Newsstand gets moved back to its default location the first time you sync your phone, so it's unfortunately a very temporary fix.

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Great find!

Comment: I can confirm - this causes a crash, good fun.

Comment: This method no longer works on iOS 5.1

Comment: This trick doesn't work on iOS 5.1 and later and isn't needed since iOS 7 allows you to put newsstand in any folder you please.

Answer (score 14):

Newsstand behaves as a folder itself.  In the same way as you cannot nest folders within folders, Newsstand cannot be placed inside any other folder.

As a side note, jailbreaking makes folder nesting possible.

You can actually get it in a folder by making a new folder and very quickly placing it in as a third item, but launching newsstand from within a folder usually causes things to crash in the phone. Furthermore, the system cleans this up when it notices it - so you have a very short term win in terms of getting newsstand in to another folder.

Until this changes in the OS - the safest thing is to move it out of sight.

Answer (score 4):

I've put in the last screen, all alone, so I never have to see that

Comment: Oddly - my first and last screen are pretty fixed - the middle few are where I bury the duds and ugly apps that I'd rather not see often.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind Jailbreaking your device, several apps allow this. One such app is NoNewsIsGoodNews which runs as an application.

http://opinionativereviewer.com/archives/3683

Comment: Requires a jailbreak though...

Comment: Yes this way is just for jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you **can** put Newsstand into a folder- from Mac or Windows. Just install

### [StifleStand](http://filippobiga.com/stiflestand/) (free)

It's really a simple application and does not require a jailbreak. I've just tested it from an iPod touch 4th gen and it really "just works".  However, note that tapping Newsstand once its in its folder causes it Springboard to crash (as mentioned by above answers).  <sup>This could be useful for a little SpringBoard restart for those who don't want to jailbreak!</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Just install the new iOS 7 (free from Apple via iTunes).

Jailbreaking and similar "hacking" procedures usually cause more problems than they promise to solve...

Comment: Why the negatives? I'm an Apple Technician, my religion forbids me to jailbreak!!!