# What tiny thing in iOS 5 makes you smile, or has caught you off guard?

Tags: ios, macos

iOS 5 is here! Geofencing, new Voices in Voice Command/Siri, and Notification Center for all!

We all know how heartfelt iOS makes you seem (Cards), how much control it gives you for managing your network (Airport Utility), and how it will easily turn you into a stalker (Find Your Friends), **but what about all the day-in and day-out things that truely make the upgrade process worth it?**

Please post only one tip per answer, and **check to see if your answer has already been posted - duplicate answers will be deleted**. To search answers for this question use `inquestion:27761` (or `inquestion:this`, while viewing this question specifically) in addition to your search terms in the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### Usage shows how much space each app is using

#### Settings -> General -> Usage

iOS 5 now collects the space used by apps and the data in the app - sorted by the largest size. If you need to free up some space quickly, this is a great way to easily identify and remove the largest burdens on your storage space.

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

*Of specific **tiny** note, the edit button in the top right allows you to delete selective content from apps like Music.*

[image]

Comment: This was clearly inspired by Android, but it looks much nicer on the iOS.

Comment: @Bora: true for many iOS 5 features.

Comment: @DanAbramov, and true vica-versa.

Answer (score 66):

### Retractable Keyboard in Messages.app

The neat way that you can scroll down on iMessages and it pulls the keyboard down with your finger.

[image]

Comment: Oh WOW. That is awesome! I hadn't even been in a position to use that yet! Great obvious addition you'll see as soon as you have to review a previous message in the conversation. Very neat!

Comment: This. As small as it seems, I desperately wanted this feature. Big help when your best friend sends you 1500-word rants via text message. :)

Answer (score 55):

### Undo Close Tab

In Safari on the iPad, tap and hold the [+] button to display a list of recently closed tabs instead of creating a new empty tab.

Answer (score 52):

### Keyboard shortcuts

I wanted this for a long time.

[image]

Comment: I've wanted those as well, but I was disappointed that you can't have shortcuts for multiline text. On the Mac, I have shortcuts for valedictions. Having that would save a lot of time on the iPhone.

Comment: I wonder if `\n` works ;) *(I'll save you 2 mins, it doesn't)*

Comment: What about `\r`? (I am being facetious.)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these work. Maybe in iOS 5.0.1...

Comment: I set the important ones like "On my way" and "I am currently driving" to be 'ooo' and 'ddd' respectively, so I can do it quickly and hopefully safely, like at a light. I like this feature a lot.

Comment: I have a shortcut that is my e-mail address.  This makes logging in to websites a lot easier, particularly since I have underscores in my e-mail address.

Comment: Use @@ for your email address and ## for your phone number

Comment: I prefer a @g for @gmail.com etc.

Answer (score 49):

### 12 Hour, Hour-by-Hour forecast

When viewing `Weather.app`, simply tapping on the screen/6 day forecast will slide the days downward, and reveal a 12 hour, hour-by-hour forecast!

Note also that "Hourly" illuminates underneath the city name when in this mode.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 49):

### Read those long song titles and artist/album names

You can tap and hold on a song/podcast title to get a pop-up of the entire description.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this feature. It only shows information that's already visible in the list. Strange. Of its unfinished, doubly strange.

Comment: @cksum: Well kind of. You can see the title of the song was truncated so the popup shows all the song info.

Comment: Moreover, it now also shows the full title when displaying the currently playing song's cover art using a marquee. It used to chop it off if it was too long before, making it especially useless for podcasts and audiobook with numbers at the *end* of the title. Have been complaining about that since iPhoneOS 1.0

Comment: Now if this could only be implemented in the iTunes app. So many podcasts prefix the title of the episode with the podcast name and you can't ever tell what the contents of that episode is.

Answer (score 48):

### Swipe Camera to view Photo Roll

When `Camera.app` is open, and you want to quickly view your previously taken photos instead, don't hit the photo button in the bottom left, simply swipe the screen from left-to-right and you will go in descending date-taken order through your Camera Roll.

Note that you cannot do this if your phone is locked and you used the 'quick camera' method, except for photos taken in that session.

[image]

This screenshot was taken mid-swipe (which is rather difficult to do). Note the `Camera.app` interface on the right half, and a [familiar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/27763#27763) [partial screenshot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/27770#27770) on the left.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Windows Phone is probably responsible for this (having done it first) as well as the physical button camera shutter. Competition at work :)

Comment: I wonder if Camera+ predates the release of Windows Phone? I honestly can't put a suitable timeline in my head at the moment.

Comment: Camera.ipa n'est-ce pas?

Comment: I don't entirely understand the question.

Comment: @VxJasonxV probably a good idea to change the screenshot to something that doesn't look like an app switching swipe... :)

Answer (score 47):

### Good Vibrations

Custom vibration patterns! (Turn them on in Accessibility; tap them out in Sounds; set them by contact in Contacts).

http://9to5mac.com/2011/06/09/ios-5-know-when-wife-is-calling-by-customizing-vibration-patterns/

Comment: That's very very cool.

Answer (score 46):

### Maps.app now features alternate routes

When getting directions that encompass a long distance that may have multiple highway routes, you will be able to choose 'Route 1' or 'Route 2' after searching the addresses, and before hitting start. Tapping on the 'Route 1'/'Route 2' tooltips will change the color for that route (light blue/dark blue) and also update the estimated distance and time in the header bar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: But does it have voice directions yet? That's the big thing that keeps my wife from using her phone as a navigator. Seems like it would be a natural fit with Siri...

Answer (score 42):

### Alternative Shutter Button

I love that you can use the volume up button to take a photo. This is great in landscape mode.

Also if you are using Apple's headphone or any headphone that compatible with iOS, using the volume `+` button from the headphone also can take a photo for you, this is great for remote shutter !

Comment: You beat me 5 seconds.

Comment: This is the first thing that struck me when I got my iPhone. It's hard to keep it still when tapping the screen.

Answer (score 38):

### Split keyboard on the iPad

Just pull the keyboard apart with your thumbs. The Hide Keyboard button (bottom right) can now be used to reposition the split keyboard on the screen. It takes some getting used to but it can be handy for typing whilst holding the iPad in your hands.

[image]

Comment: It also "undocks", press and hold the keyboard button.

Comment: Huh. I never even thought to pull apart the keyboard, I always just used the retraction icon and the "grips" that were added to it. But need that you can just expand it apart!

Comment: Yay typos. But neat*, that you can just expand it apart.

Comment: I love the animation of it.

Answer (score 35):

### Draggable Recipients

You can drag and drop recipients between To, Cc and Bcc in Mail app.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the hand contortion or outside assistance it must have required for you to be able to take this screenshot.

Answer (score 34):

### Swipe Individual Notifications

My favorite mini-feature yet: **you can swipe any notification on the lock screen**.
This will remove the lock *and* proceed to the relevant app.

[image]

Comment: This one is so good and intuitive, I didn't even THINK about mentioning this was new.

Comment: By hold you mean lock, correct?

Comment: @Josh: yeah. Don't know what's wrong with me..

Answer (score 33):

### Third Party Audio Apps Can Publish Song Data to Lock Screen / Multitasking Bar

In previous versions of iOS, the lock screen and multitasking bar would simply show the app name that's playing music. But now, if supported in the app/implemented by the developer, full Artist, Album, and Title information can be shown instead.

[image]
[image]

Note the non-Music.app icon in the multitasking bar.

Comment: +1 because (a) I wish my Android phone had a better OEM lock screen and (b) **Skrillex**

Comment: I'm looking forward to Spotify implementing this :)

Comment: I saw Soundcloud doing that in iOS 4.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you didn't. Apps previously had no way to be able to do that. Because apps couldn't "change their name" in order to show something different in the multitasking bar / lock screen. There was no SDK mechanism like there is now to publish this data.

Comment: And yet, while soundcloud was playing, I certainly saw soundcloud in the place of ipod icon in the multitasking bar. Not sure about the locked screen, though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. The icon of the currently playing application is not new, that's been around since the multitasking bar existed (iOS 4); the name of the song is the part that is new.

Answer (score 33):

### Dictionary

Word definitions from text selections.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not just text editing apps. It also works on most apps that display text and let you select it such as Safari or the web browser component.

Comment: I've updated the answer to put this more clearly, I hurried to get the thing posted with the pics and didn't think about wording properly.

Comment: How does this work? I mean, how can I get those "definitions"?

Comment: Just tap the right arrow on the `copy | cut` selected text menu, and there's the `define` option, or tap left to go back.

Comment: It does not work for me. I get the "copy|cut" button, but there are no arrows. iPhone 4, iOS 5, German.

Comment: Sad it works only when editing text (not when reading).. :(

Answer (score 29):

### Current Volume Reminder

Switching the phone from Silent mode back to normal now displays the current ringer volume.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

### 6 day forecast in Weather Widget for Notification Center

When in the Notification Center drawer, you can swipe the Current Weather widget in either direction to switch between Current Local Conditions, to the same 6 day forecast you would see in `Weather.app`. Saves a ton of time!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no reason for Hanging with Friends to be abbreviated in such a manner... thanks Zynga :/.

Answer (score 27):

### MobileSafari, Mobile Reader

The **Reader** button in *Mobile Safari* address bar.

It displays a page not entirely suited for mobile in an easy to read, black-and-white format.  It removes all of the extraneous information and focuses on the body text.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:** Something new I noticed recently, if the article has a link such as "Continued on page 2...", the Reader will automatically load the additional pages, allowing you to scroll through the entire article without leaving the Reader.

Comment: I was so happy when I saw this.

Comment: I remember seeing this as a feature for normal Safari and thinking, meh. But on the iPhone this feature is gold!

Comment: Is this only available on the iPhone 4S? I don't see it on my iPhone 4. Do I have to enable it somehow?

Comment: @jessegavin, I have an iPhone 4.  It seems to only appear on certain pages, usually those with a single article.  It doesn't appear if you have a string of blog entries (multiple articles) or a forum listing.  Also you have to wait for the whole page to load first.  Try a news site so you can see it in action.

Comment: @jesse, It is up to the website developer to “mark” content as an article. Most news websites and blogs already do this, but not all.

Comment: Per your edit, that's the whole point of Reader mode. Well, it's one of the main two points. (1) Uniform/Clean Presentation, (2) Single Page

Answer (score 25):

### Ability to edit the colours of Exchange calendars

Finally, I can make the colours of each Exchange calendar consistent, without needing to [buy a Mac, to use iCal](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/01/23/how-to-really-change-the-calendar-colors-on-your-iphone/)!

To change the colours:

1. Click on the **Calendars** button
2. Click on **Edit**
3. Click on the **">" button** next to a calendar
4. Pick the Colour of your choice...

[image: iPad calendar colour-selection dialog]

A nice extra touch is that if you use a 3rd-party calendar app, such as Informant HD, the same colours are used there too.

Comment: I was excited to see my colors change since I use Google Sync. Now I'm really excited I can change them on the phone itself :D

Comment: OK, I did NOT know that. :D

Answer (score 25):

### Additional Data in Calendar when Rotated

Calendar.app when the iPhone is rotated in landscape mode displays a week mode.

Horizontal scroll iterates through days.
Vertical scroll iterates through hours.

Comment: WHOA! I have never seen anyone mention this feature before. This is extremely useful for the first couple weeks of each quarter when I need to see my classes for the week.

Answer (score 24):

### Emoji for everybody!

Emoji is now a keyboard that can be used by anybody, where prior to iOS 5 it would only be enabled by the use of a Softbank (Japanese Cell Phone Carrier) SIM card in your device, or via special tricks that [certain applications](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spell-number-get-emoji-smiley/id284858425?mt=8) would perform.

Enable it by going into Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> International Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard, then scroll about 1/3rd of the way down and tap 'Emoji'.

Emoji are cute little detailed picture icons. These icons can only generally be seen on Apple computers, iPhone users, or most Japanese Cell Phones (albeit they will look quite a bit different on those).

Comment: There's a special easter egg for users viewing this answer in Safari, or on an iOS device, only. Chrome users (like myself, unfortunately) cannot see it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant Safari users *on Lion*. On Safari on SL, I see only the boxes (as with Chrome)

Comment: So, as we see here:  This is fun, but beware that sending an email with emoji in it will result in little boxes for the recipient unless he is using iOS or Lion... For example, if he is using Windows.

Comment: @GEdgar why would you want to email a Windows user anyway?! :P

Comment: E-mailing you at Stack Exchange would mean e-mailing a Windows user :(.

Comment: There's nothing particuarly special about those characters - they're just Unicode. They show for me in Linux. For example, character #6 is the example is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm

Comment: This is 100% true, but the fact that you can input them easily on an iPhone is relatively special :). I mean, I've been entering Unicode on a phone since my Sidekick 2, but this method is 1098530974298712x easier.

Answer (score 24):

Double tapping the home button on the lock screen shows you both media controls, and a camera icon to the right of the unlock swiping track. Not only is the Camera available from the lock screen, but as soon as you push the home button, it whisks you right back to the lock screen. So nobody can get into your iPhone without unlocking it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the phone is locked, and you tap the camera button it opens up the camera app. But if you then click the home button is takes you to the home screen, not the lock screen

Comment: @hopeless That happens to me too, but I think it's a bug. Or maybe it depends on whether you have a pass code set.

Comment: Pressing the home button takes you to the lock screen with the pin input panel raised if you have a passcode set.

Answer (score 23):

### More convenient "Find On Page" searching

I just noticed that when you're in Safari, and you click in the Search box at the top-right, the keyboard has a new "Find on Page" box, that is much more convenient than the old iOS 4 way of searching.

[image]

**Edit: 20/10/2011**

The Pad Gadget page [iPad Quick Tip – Find Text and Keywords in Mobile Safari](http://www.padgadget.com/2010/12/02/ipad-quick-tip-%E2%80%93-find-text-and-keywords-in-mobile-safari/) shows a screenshot from the iOS 4 days. Notice how the "On this page" bit appears after it's searched the Web. My point is that the iOS 5 way is more obvious, and more convenient.

Comment: iPad-only, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't like how you only get this after tapping the search box, however. It makes sense considering the way to do it before, but it doesn't generally make sense. Well, maybe. Different kinds of search :/.

Comment: I didn't even know the old Safari had in-page search. This is pretty cool..

Comment: This isn't iPad-only; you have to start typing text before "Find in Page (n matches)" will show in the bottom of the results.

Comment: @SteveShaner - That was there before iOS5.

Answer (score 23):

### Mass Mark as Read/Unread/Flag

You can now mark multiple emails as Read/Unread from the edit mode in Mail without having to open each message.

[image]

Comment: Ignore iCloud, this and the hole + in iPad safari for recently closed tabs, is way more worth the upgrade process.

Comment: @djacobson - Please expand on how this is done.

Answer (score 20):

### Ringtones (can) Serve Double Duty as Notification Tones

Ringtones that are less than 15 seconds will also show up in the the various other notification types.

New (SMS) Message, Calendar Alerts, Tweet Sent, etc. They can even be defined as the SMS tone for a specific contact in your Address Book.

Comment: It was about time! :)

Answer (score 20):

### Rename Your iOS Device

I can change my iPod's name without using a computer.

Silly I know, but I can.

`Settings.app > General > About > Name`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: PC-Free is the way to be. Cut the Cord!

Comment: @VxJasonxV Got that right! Side note: I haven't changed my iPod's name back yet. ;)

Comment: @VxJasonxV: Is that a reference to the old commercials that use to say "Drug-free is the way to be" or did I just have a weird deja-vu moment?

Comment: You just had a weird déjà vu moment.

Comment: I'm not so happy to have my private data under someone else's control. But it is a smart business.

Answer (score 19):

### Ghost Buttons on the iPad's Split Keyboard

Many have complained about the split keyboard not matching their natural finger choice for the middle letters (TY / GH / VB), but as it turns out, those keys all exist on the both sides of the keyboard. Want to hit Y with your left finger? Do it, it's there, and it's really wide too, easily 3 buttons wide. Want to hit V with your right finger? Do it, same rules apply. It's really amazingly well done.

Hat tip to [Finer Things in iOS](http://ios.finerthingsin.com/post/16982049392/ipad-keyboard-phantom-buttons?56aaf7e0):

[image]

Answer (score 17):

### Multi-touch gestures on iPad

1. Pinch to close app
2. Swipe up with four fingers to show the app switcher
3. Swipe left/right with four fingers to switch between running apps

I'm finding number 3 less useful so far but 1 and 2 are becoming second nature.

Comment: It kinda sucks but this feature existed for iPad 1 in iOS 4.3. They pulled this out in iOS 5.

Comment: I enjoy using 1 and 3 (3 is a real time saver), hadn't found 2 yet.

Comment: You can enable them on a jailbroken iPad 1 by setting SBUseSystemGestures to true in /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist.

Comment: Gestures are returning to the first iPad in iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: iOS 5.0.1 makes this appear on iPad 1 :)

Comment: I love this feature. I never use the home button anymore. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

### Notifications allows control over badge counts

If you prefer icons to be clean and without status - specifically in apps like Mail, notifications allows fine grained control over displaying a badge or not.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

### You can send and receive iPhone FaceTime calls via email addresses

This is nothing new to iPod touch or iPad users, but up until iOS 5 iPhone users could only send or receive FaceTime calls with their phone number. Now you can add one or more email addresses to the FaceTime section in Settings to enable people to FaceTime you at those addresses. You can also configure the Caller ID to be either the phone number or any of the email addresses - useful to prevent people you FaceTime with from getting your phone number.

You also have the same flexibility with iMessage as well, the ability to send and receive messages from either your phone number of any number of email addresses.

[image] [image]

Comment: This is now feature-equal with OS X's `Facetime.app`, and that helps, a lot.

Comment: You should mention the same goes for iMessage too.

Answer (score 13):

### More dash types

Tap and hold the dash on the keyboard now gives an en–dash (in addition to the -hyphen, em—dash and bullet •). Not very useful but it made me smile :–)

Comment: It actually was present in iOS 4, I used that before.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Before it was only the hyphen and em-dash. The en-dash is new.

Comment: Truly a typography geek's feature. Makes me happy. :)

Answer (score 12):

### iForgot My Password

When signing into the App Store, the "forgot password" button is labelled "iForgot":

[image]

Comment: Hahahhaa. That doesn't seem like a typical Apple thing to do. Some sneaky dev must have put that in there last second.

Answer (score 10):

### LED Flash on Alerts

I use this in combination with vibrate to wake myself and not the other half.

Settings > General > Accessibility > LED Flash for Alerts

Works best with a transparent or semi transparent cover, ie. they glow with the phone lying flat on a table.

Comment: I tried this, but it's a full flash so it's very bright.

Comment: iPhone 4 or greater only

Answer (score 10):

### Private Browsing Mode for MobileSafari

MobileSafari now has a private browsing mode, turn it on and off under Settings -> Safari. Additionally, it's chrome turns black when Private Browsing is on.

Useful so you can buy your wife presents without her finding out.

Comment: Right, presents for the wife...  ;-)  Just teasing!

Answer (score 10):

### Lock Camera Exposure+Focus

To keep Camera exposure & focus LOCKED at where you want it, tap the screen & HOLD it until the box pulses.

via [@Photojojo](https://twitter.com/#!/Photojojo/status/126409821623820288)

Comment: I had no idea about this one, very nice.

Answer (score 10):

### You can now delete individual items in your call history

When viewing your call history, you can hit "edit" in the upper right and delete individual items from your call history.

[image]

via [@negrino](https://twitter.com/negrino/status/126742710861312000)

Comment: As with any other editable list, you can also swipe individual items as opposed to tapping edit first.

Comment: You can also delete your Music on device in the same manner.

Answer (score 9):

### Siri can be activated at the lock screen without a passcode

You can use Siri to call, text, and email from the lock screen **without a passcode**.

Didn't make me smile, but caught me off guard.

Luckily, you can disable Siri at the lock screen by going to Settings-> General-> Passcode Lock turning the Siri switch to Off.

Comment: But aint siri an iphone 4S feature rather than ios 5 ?

Comment: Yes, but do we really need an *additional* thread called "What tiny thing in iPhone 4S makes you smile, or has caught you off guard?" :)

Comment: Siri is new to iOS 5. Of course, Voice Control has been like this since, like, iOS 3. And the same tip holds true for it.

Comment: @VxJasonxV Siri is new to iPhone 4S. It's not an iOS 5 feature, otherwise it would be available e.g. for iPhone 4's. There just is no iPhone 4s with iOS 4.

Comment: Well heard someone is trying to port Siri to iPhone 4. Can't wait to check it out.

Answer (score 9):

### Speak to me (not related to Siri)

One new feature I haven't seen mentioned much is that you can now add a 'Speak' option to every text selection popup, so you can read SMSes or web pages. You can turn it on in the Settings -> General -> Accessibility.

Works on all devices on all selectable text.

[image]

Comment: Note that this does not require a 4S and has nothing to do with Siri.

Comment: There are a lot of good Accessibility features that no one knows about.

Comment: Uh, I don't get it. If I can read the screen and select the words I want, then why do I need to have it read aloud? What's the use case for this?

Comment: There are a lot of good accessibility features, which should just be normal features.

Comment: @Styfle - "a lot of good Accessibility features that no one knows about" ... ironic that accessibility to the accessibility features is so poor.

Comment: @slomojo: Hahaha, I didn't even think about that. It's probably "hard to find" because most people aren't looking for it. These are features I didn't even know I wanted. But out of all the menus in iOS 5, Accessibility is the most cluttered.

Comment: As Steve Yegge skillfully pointed out in his [leaked google+ post](https://plus.google.com/112678702228711889851/posts/eVeouesvaVX), Accessibility is really important, and doesn't really mean what we tend to think it does... Accessibility is every way that humans interact with computers.

Answer (score 8):

### Additional "Clear Skies at Night" Icons in Weather.app

When in [12 hour forecast mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/27763#27763), or when it is the night time, there are new icons in the forecast area that resemble a starry sky, as opposed to a daytime sun, indicating clear weather.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I actually don't like this feature. The moon without clouds is more parallel to the sun. And the first time I saw the stars, I thought it was snow. Which was very confusing, since it's still 84F here.

Comment: You know, I'll agree with you on that second part, I too thought it said snow, which isn't unreasonable for Colorado in this season :). I still like the stars though.

Comment: Looks like snow to me....

Answer (score 8):

## Swiping right when reading e-mail displays message list in portrait mode on iPad

You no longer have to reach for the top left button to show that list.

If you do not wind up selecting a message, a simple swipe left in the message content pane, not in the folder/message list, will retract it.

Answer (score 8):

### Find My Friends

For parents of a teenager, this is a great way to track where the kids are.

The ability to remove the app or remove 'friends' can be restricted with parental restrictions. This combo alone is worth getting the kid an iPhone.

"I see you're 1 mile from Home Depot. Please get me a box of 2" drywall screws." Creepy. I know. But we got used to caller ID quick enough.

Comment: Note that you can use parental controls to enforce this, actively prevent them from changing options.

Comment: I want to +1 this for the example alone, but Find My iPhone is not a new iOS 5 feature :(.

Comment: This answer can be changed to the Find my Friends app instead, which is new with iOS 5 and actually better for tracking teenagers anyway. You can mention that the ability to remove the app or remove 'friends' can be restricted with parental restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

### In-app Download Progress Indicators

Podcasts that are downloading are shown in the Music app with a circular completion icon that fills clockwise until the download completes at the 12 o'clock mark.
This may also apply to albums/songs.

[image]

Comment: excellent taste in podcasts :)

Comment: This does indeed apply to anything being downloaded in the music, movies, and a few other apps.

Answer (score 6):

### Pause a Timer

I really like the pause button for timers in Clocks.app. A tiny little thing, but so much nicer than having to change the timer to the nearest minute, and restart.

Answer (score 5):

## Long track titles, artist names, album names scroll to display the full title

In the example below, the full title of the song is "One Sunday Morning (Song for Jane Smiley's Boyfriend".

[image: Long track title scrolling example]

Comment: This snswer is related to another way of [viewing very long song titles/album titles/artist names](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/28131#28131).

Answer (score 4):

### Easily view a location in a calendar event

The Location field in a Calendar event links to Maps.app provided there is enough information for the data detector to recognize it as an address.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually **backspace** on the numbers you enter in **Calculator**, instead of having to clear them all.

Just swipe horizontally on the numbers on the display: it will remove the last entered number.

Pretty nifty.

Comment: I was going to command and say "surely you mean right to left" as would be expected with any another app, but after opening Calculator.app I realized that the numbers do come out FROM the right. However, I will note that swiping in either direction (left to right OR right to left) will remove a number. Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

Double tap screen in camera video mode to change aspect ratio to widescreen.  I have yet to confirm, but this may only work on the iPhone 4S.

Comment: Hey, that's pretty neat. Nice find!

Answer (score 3):

### Photo Edit Rotation

In the Photos app, you can rotate by any degree, not just at specific intervals, by pressing crop and then using two fingers to rotate the image.

Answer (score 3):

### Landscape Orientation Lock on the iPhone

On the iPhone you can lock the orientation into Landscape by doing this once:

- Going to Settings.app → General → Accessibility
- Setting Triple Click Home (the bottom setting) to AssistiveTouch

Then when you want to set orientation lock:

- Enable Portrait Orientation Lock from the multitasking/app-switcher bar
- Triple press the home button
- Press the white circle that appears
- Press Device
- Rotate Screen
- Choose which orientation to lock to.
- Press the home button 3 times again to get rid of the white circle/overview.

An annoyingly overlong but sometimes useful ability, that should have implemented by default.

Answer (score 3):

### View third-party app art at Lock Screen exclusively

When using an app that publishes song information/cover art to the lock screen (e.g. Music.app, Spotify), you can tap anywhere on the Lock Screen except an actual lock screen element (bars, unlock slider, etc.) to hide all of the lock screen's bars and other information in order to have a clean picture of nothing but the cover art, taking the place of your lock screen wallpaper.

While playing music via Spotify, the lock screen normally:

[image: Lock screen with Spotify playing music]

After tapping the background (tapping any of the bar areas will not work):

[image: Lock screen with interface chrome removed]

*Note:*

- This appears to be an iPad-only feature.
- You cannot do this when your normal lock screen wallpaper is shown.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5.1 you can swipe up on the camera icon in the lock screen to take a photo - most people know that.  However you can *also* **swipe down to re-lock the phone once done with the camera.**

via http://www.quora.com/iOS-5/What-are-the-best-new-features-on-iOS-5-users-probably-havent-discovered-yet/answer/Ron-Levy

Comment: Or simply tap the sleep/power button.

Comment: This feature was new in iOS 5.1, changed from the behaviour in 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

### Bluetooth Volume Control, and Bluetooth Text Display

Simply that the volume control on my stereo bluetooth headphones now actually controls the volume of my iPod Touch - AND the currently playing track is displayed on the Bluetooth module. Looks like they've sorted that one good and proper!

Comment: I suspect that's related to the work for [3rd party apps being able to publish song info](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard/27773#27773). But I am quite curious, what BT device do you have that has a screen and will display this information?

Comment: My car can display the current track.  In the past, it did not display with BlueTooth, but it did display when the iPhone was plugged in with USB.  I guess I haven't payed attention since iOS5 to see if there was a change.

Comment: Do you know if this is a iOS 5 feature or a 4S feature? My car is supposed to display Bluetooth track info, but still doesn't for my 4 with iOS 5.

Comment: @Emily - this works on my car radio with an iPhone 4 and iOS 5

Answer (score 2):

### Unified Single Caller Log

I'm not sure when this happened, but I only just noticed it, but when viewing the recent calls list, of you click the little arrow next to the caller name on the right, you get a detailed list of the relevant calls.  This was there before, but only showed completed calls, not is shows cancelled calls where you hung up before receiving an answer or voicemail.  Using for proving you tried to call, although it won't show "call failed", it will show cancelled in it's place where a call did actually fail, like for me earlier today...

[image]

Comment: In older versions of iOS, this would only show you "closely related" call times (within maybe a rolling half hour?). That amount of time appears to have been raised dramatically.

Comment: If only they would timestamp each SMS too...

Answer (score 2):

### Quickly access most recent draft email

Hold the compose button to bring up the most recent draft email

(via http://obamapacman.com/2012/02/how-to-quickly-save-access-saved-mail-draft-on-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch/)

Answer (score 1):

### The Immortal Newsstand

Newsstand caught me off guard, but then in a [bad way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/how-can-i-get-rid-of-newsstand). It caught me off guard because I was not expecting Apple to add a feature I cannot remove or even move to another folder without ["cheating"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/can-i-put-newsstand-into-a-folder).

Comment: It's what the last screen is for, all the unremovable stuff. ;)

Answer (score 0):

iMessage supports animated gifs!

But unfortunately as of iOS 5.0.1 only animated within the message bubble - it is not animated when you tap/select the image to view full screen.

Comment: Do this mean it animated everywhere on 5.0? Or didn't animate at all?

Comment: And in Lion, too! :D

Answer (score 0):

Music fades in volume but continues to play when a phone call is received — this appears to be added in iOS 5.1.

Comment: On further use this may be a bug as it doesn't seem to always happen (reliably or consistently), or only a partially supported feature.  Trying to get to the bottom of this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3836857