# What are some iOS5-only and/or iPhone 4S-only Hidden Tips/Tricks?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tiny thing in iOS 5 makes you smile, or has caught you off guard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard)

Be sure to specify if your tip or trick is for all iOS5 devices, or if it is restricted to the iPhone 4S only.

Comment: Should be a community wiki, no?

Answer (score -1):

iOS5 Camera Tip: To keep your auto exposure & focus fixed at where you want it, just tap the screen & hold it until the box pulses.

via [@Photojojo](https://twitter.com/#!/Photojojo/status/126409821623820288)

Comment: This is (1) Not new (2) Not iOS5-only (3) Not iPhone 4S only.

Comment: Wrong on #1 and #2, and as the original topic stated, this is for iOS5 and/OR 4S.  This is a new iOS5 feature!

Comment: June 2009, iPhone 3GS, iOS 3, Tap to Focus - http://reviews.cnet.com/2300-6454_7-10001061-9.html?s=0&o=10001061
Forum thread of the same details as above. - http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/general-talk/62787-iphone-3gs-tap-focus.html
iPhone 4, iOS 4, July 2010 - http://www.theiphoneguru.net/2010/07/20/iphone-ios-4-tip-tap-to-focus-and-zoom-in-camera/

You're wrong.

Comment: The links you've provided only reference tap to focus, I'm talking about tap and HOLD to lock exposure and focus.