# Does the iPhone 4 still vibrate in your ear if you receive a text message during a call?

Tags: iphone, ios

With iOS 5 upon us, does the iPhone 4 still [vibrate in your ear](http://www.tipb.com/2010/12/06/ios-42-bugs-iphone-vibrates-ears-call/) if you receive a text message (or any kind of notification) during a call?

Comment: If the answer is no, that's definitely something to be added to [this list](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-tiny-thing-in-ios-5-makes-you-smile-or-has-caught-you-off-guard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried with text messages, but with Whatsapp and emails it does, unfortunately :(

So to answer the second part of your question, yes notifications vibrates during call.

Comment: I'm assuming the same would apply to text messages then. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if it vibrates (if silent), but it most certainly plays notification sounds for text messages.