# Can Spotlight search for text within Safari for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, ios, spotlight

Is there a way to search text within Safari by doing a Spotlight search on an iPhone? There currently is no such way to run a find/search within Safari (boo), so I need a work around.

Answer (score 2):

No, Spotlight doesn't search the current page from within Mobile Safari (but it does search Reading List and other saved/bookmarked pages) but you don't need a workaround since this function exists in Safari.

It used to look like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/27960/5472).

On iOS 9, it's integrated with the main search field - begin like you're searching for a new web page and then scroll down to "On this page"

[image]

Once you tap that, you get this interface to pan to each instance of the search results with the term highlighted.

[image]