# How can I get rid of Newsstand?

Tags: applications, ios, ipad

After the upgrade to iOS-5, I got the Newsstand app "for free". I don't use it and I probably never will. Is there any way, short of jail breaking, for me to remove it from my iPad2?

I know that I can [put it in a folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/can-i-put-newsstand-into-a-folder), but can I remove it entirely?

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27402/9058

Comment: Crap, I don't use it on my phone and thought I could bury it in a folder with other stuff I don't use but alas, you're right, it can't be moved into a folder, at least as far as I can tell. I find it useful on my iPad but not iPhone.

Comment: Since the folder part of this question has already been asked, I edited the question to focus on the other part, removing Newsstand entirely. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I know Newsstand seems like a extraneous feature for a "power user." I myself thought this. But give it a try. Just with the NYTimes app and the New Yorker app, I've found Newsstand to be much cooler and more useful than I would have imagined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Like all iOS applications coming pre-installed, Newsstand cannot be removed from an iOS device. See the [Apple Support Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=&dateRange=all&peopleEnabled=false&q=delete+newsstand&containerType=&container=&containerName=&username=&rankBy=relevance&numResults=15) for corroboration.