# How can I move the newstand app into a folder?

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I put Newsstand into a folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/can-i-put-newsstand-into-a-folder)

How can I create a folder for the pre-installed apps that come on my ipad that I don't use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Perhaps unless you jailbreak your device first.

Comment: I created a folder and moved them a while ago but now I can't remember how I did it. I want to move my newsstand into it too. ...somehow I was able to slide them into the folder. I remember that the timing was crucial, but I can't manage to do it again. Suggestions?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/can-i-put-newsstand-into-a-folder